# Symfony webpage not showing when I extend base.html.twig

Tags: php, html, css, symfony, twig

I'm using Symfony on a new project, and I've just created a controller and a template to begin. My controller:

```
 public function index(){
    return $this->render('character/index.html.twig');
}
```

My base.html.twig

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

And my index.html.twig:

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}

{% block stylesheets %}<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/style.css') }}"/> {%  endblock %}

{%  block title %}Gamer{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div>Test</div>
{% endblock %}
```

When I access this page, it is blank, no error. When I delete the line

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}
```

from my index.html.twig, I can see my page. I don't understand why is base.hmtl.twig not working. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Your `base` doesn't has the block `content` defined

Comment: Ohhhh okay I'm so dumb, I understand now, thanks a lot!